# Multiple one to many tables filtering on lower table value

Tags: sql

I have three tables with one to many relationships which is `Table A` to `Table B` to `Table C` which further details are stored down the line. Structure per the below:

```
`-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|  TABLE_A     |    |        TABLE_B       | |        TABLE_C              |
----------------    ------------------------ ------------------------------
| A_ID | A_DATA|    | B_ID | A_ID | B_DATA | | C_ID | B_ID | A_ID | C_DATA |
---------------     ------------------------ ------------------------------`
```

I have written a query using join `Table A` to `Table B` and `Table B` to `Table C`and have added further filers using fields on each table.

```
`SELECT * from TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.A_ID=B.A_ID
JOIN TABLE_C C ON B.B_ID = C.B_ID
WHERE A.A_DATA='Some Parameter'
and B.B_DATA='Some Parameter'
and C.C_DATA<>'Some Parameter';`
```

Is it possible to filter out data from table A if it has data both satisfying and not-satisfying the condition `C.C_DATA<>'Some Parameter'`?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result that shows what you mean with _both satisfying and not-satisfying_. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using too. thx

Comment: You are joining TABLE B with A.A_ID=B.B_ID. Wouldnt it be A.A_ID=B.A_ID? Same goes for TABLE C as well.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use an exists and a coorlated subquery or not exists.... `select * from table_A where not exists (Select C.Data from table_C where Table_A.A_ID = table_C.A_ID)`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

For the snippet you have posted, it will filter out any record that doesn't satisfy all conditions on your WHERE clause. For that matter, you may need to push these WHERE conditions before JOINS.

For ex

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id= B.id
WHERE A.param1 = 'abc'
AND B.param2 = 'cba';
```

is totally different from

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.param1 = 'abc') A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.param2 = 'cba') B
ON A.id = B.id;
```

The first SQL will join all records matching ids and filter it out. In the second one, it filters records first and then joins all records matching ids.